# Name of threads in S3TransferManager's executor service

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am using following code to get S3TransferManager reference to upload a mulitipart file to S3 bucket. File upload happens fine but in logs I see Threads uploading multipart file are named as Thread-2, Thread-4 ..... I was expecting them to be named as s3-uploader-2, s3-uploader-4. What am I missing here? Please advise.

```
private S3TransferManager getTransferManager(S3AsyncClient s3ac){
    S3TransferManager s3tm = S3TransferManager.builder().executor(createExecutiveService(10, "s3-uploader-")).s3Client(s3ac).build();
    return s3tm;
}

private ThreadPoolExecutor createExecutiveService(int threadCount, String threadNamePrefix){
    ThreadFactory tfb = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().threadNamePrefix(threadNamePrefix).build();
    return (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount, tfb);
}
```